# How to reduce nested if-else condition?

Tags: php, if-statement, nested, reduce

I do a lot of nested if-else condition in my code. It's about 34 times i do it. You know, It's really driving me crazy. Please tell me how to reduce it. Thank  you.

and here my code :

```
if ($input_age > $age_min && $input_age <$age_max){
 if ($input_heigh > $heigh_min && $input_heigh < $heigh_max){
    if ($input_ds == "yes" && $ds_val=="yes" ){ 
    //some calculation
    }
    else if ($input_ds == "no" && $ds_val=="yes"){ 
    //some calculation

    }
    else if ($input_ds == "yes" && $ds_val=="no"){ 
    //some calculation

    }
    else if ($input_ds == "no" && $ds_val=="no"){ 

    //some calculation  

    }
}
else if ($input_heigh < $heigh_min || $input_heigh > $heigh_max){
    if ($input_ds == "yes" && $ds_val=="yes" ){
    //some calculation

    }
    else if ($input_ds == "no" && $ds_val=="yes" ){ 
    //some calculation

    }

    else if ($input_ds == "yes" && $ds_val=="no"){ 
    //some calculation

    }
    else if ($input_ds == "no" && $ds_val=="no" ){ 
    //some calculation

    }
}
```

and many more if-else conditon

Comment: Is it the nested layout you dont like? As you could just refactor the code into functions to handle each calculation, to make the code easier to read.

Comment: @gunnx -did you read my mind ? i was about to write something similar..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use switch in such cases it is much more readable. Here is simple example:

```
switch($input_ds.$ds_val){
   case 'yesyes':
      //some calculations
      break;
   case 'yesno':
      //some calculations
      break;
   case 'noyes':
      //some calculations
      break;
   case 'nono':
      //some calculations
      break;
}
```

Comment: Glad I read this, I didn't know you could use a switch like that.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: Thank you, but it still use if-else condition, rite? It will not reduce the else-if condition I guess.

Comment: It will reduce else-if condition, in this example switch reduce all elseif cond from first if block of Your code